# List all entries of 'Lock Screen' events from logs

Tags: terminal, logs

I am trying to access the logs that show when the screen was locked (e.g Apple Icon > Lock Screen). After looking in the Console app I think the event is called 'kAELockScreenEvent', but I am not sure.

I can query these events from the terminal with the following code, but it takes forever to dig through all the logs. Can it be done faster by looking in a specific log or with another method?

`log show --process 'loginwindow: [com.apple.loginwindow.logging:Standard]' --predicate 'logType = default' --info --color non--start 2021-10-17 | grep 'kAELockScreenEvent'`

Comment: Looks like you've got a bit of a syntax error in your script args there, I think `--color non--start 2021-10-17` isn't what you meant. Did you mean `--color none --start 2021-10-17`?